# Which shell is shipped on default installs?

Tags: command-line

Recently started playing with Ubuntu. I am playing with few shell scripts written for Korn Shell that I want to edit in Ubuntu. What shell does Ubuntu runs on? I guess its Bash? If it is, then is there any way to install or run a particular script under a particular shell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default scripting shell (`/bin/sh`) is *dash*. The default interactive shell (`/bin/bash`) is *bash*. When using scripts on Ubuntu that are using `/bin/sh` you may need to avoid various "bashisms", like arrays or {}-style globbing.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is `bash`. To run a script you have to type `./script_name` or `sh script_name`

Comment: Hi Pawel, Can I run a script written from ksh under bash?

Comment: well, a lot ksh scripts will run without any problems under bash. You simply have to try :) before running a script, it may be necessary to execute command: `chmod +x script_name`

Comment: But is it possible to install any other shell?

Comment: "sh" is a symlink to `dash`, so "sh script_name" should be "bash script_name" if you want to use bashisms.

Comment: Yes, you can install any shell you want. Just use sudo aptitude install ksh