# CTRL-Alt-t opens term executes a command and exits

Tags: shortcuts, command-line

How do I get to the options screen that sets the command to run and whether to close right away or not.

I think I need to get to the "Edit, Profiles" and change the default one. I set it to close immediately after the command executes (which was a bogus command). The window does not stay open long enough for me to be able to change how it is supposed to behave.

Comment: I replaced ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/%gconf.xml with known good settings from another pc, but it does not seem to take.

I then rebooted, which I am thinking, made the profiles reload. This fixed it.

Is there a way to do it manually?

Answer (score 2):

If it’s a file that runs a command, you can simply destroy the file.

You also can edit the XML file which contains Terminal profiles settings manually. It’s under `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles`. Open it with a text editor, search for the line with the name `exit_action` and change **close** to **hold**:

```
<entry name="exit_action" mtime="1379127373" type="string">
    <stringvalue>hold</stringvalue>
```

**Alternatively**, you can find the line with the name `use_custom_command` and change its value to false:

```
<entry name="use_custom_command" mtime="1379127167" type="bool" value="false"/>
```

To prevent future problems, keep the Profile settings to always hold the terminal open:

[image: hold terminal]

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily override the custom command by specifying another [as a command-line parameter](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gnome-terminal). Specify the [default shell](https://askubuntu.com/q/13536/1859) to get a usable terminal window:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `gnome-terminal --command bash`.
2. Go to **Edit ▸ Profile Preferences ▸ Title and Command** and disable or correct the custom command.